# PDFs not printing correctly on PC

Tags: pdf, printer

I have 2 HP LaserJet 1200 series printers in my office. One for my PC, and one for my secretary's PC. I am having trouble printing PDFs (especially large ones) to my HP LaserJet 1200.

I dont believe it is the printer itself, because i traded it with the secretaries, and she is able to print fine on it from her computer. I have since switched them back again.

It must be some setting on my PC? Or do i need to reinstall Adobe Reader?

Comment: What "trouble" are you having? You might also want to [edit] your question and supply some more details, like which exact Operating System, how you connect the printers, which drivers you have, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your secretary can print fine (the same document to both printers), then we have obviously isolated the issue to your machine.

I doubt it is Acrobat reader itself, but, it can never hurt to upgrade when having issues like this.

I think the most probable reason is bad printer drivers and I would recommend you try to update these.